# Evaluate a limit $\lim_{n \to -1} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$

Tags: calculus, limits

I don't understand how comes $\lim_{n \to -1^{-}} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n=\infty$, while $\lim_{n \to -1^{+}} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n=-\infty$.

Comment: As kahen commented on my half-nonsensical answer, the second limit expression is problematic.  When $-1<n<0$, $\frac1{n}<-1$, so $1+\frac1{n}<0$.  In that case, what does $(1+\frac1{n})^n$ mean?  If $a<0$ then $a^m$ is clearly defined only when $m$ is an integer.  Somehow Wolfram Alpha agrees that the limit is $-\infty$.

Comment: Wolfram must be taken as what it is: a very helpful resource that sometimes goes berserk.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e^{n\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)}$$

When $\;n\to -1^+\;$ we have that $\;1+\frac 1n<0\;$ , and raising negative numbers to some powers can be pretty nonsensical in the reals of real numbers (for example, any power which is a rational number with an even numerator), so the function isn't defined (you can see this, of course, also from the fact that the logarithmic function is defined **only** for positive reals).

But from the left is fine: the logarithmic part approaches $\;-\infty\;$ times something very close to $\;-1\;$ equals, in the limit, $\;+\infty$